# How to Add few lines from a file to the beginning of another?

Tags: unix, sed

I used sed to extract the first 69 lines from a file.

```
sed -n '1,69p' file.vcf > header.vcf
```

How can I put this on the beginning (Fist line), of another file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method for those 69 lines at the beginning of file `other.vcf` is:

```
{ head -n69 file.vcf; cat other.vcf; } >tmp$$ && mv tmp$$ other.vcf
```

`head -n69 file.vcf` outputs the first 69 lines of `file.vcf`.  `cat other.vcf` outputs the whole of `other.vcf`.  `>tmp$$` captures that output in a temporary file.  If the creation of the temporary file was successful, `&& mv tmp$$ other.vcf` causes `other.vcf` to be replaced with the new version.

Comment: Thank you for both, solution and explanation of each piece of the code.
Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i -e '69r other.vcf' -e '69q' header.vcf
```

Use `-i` flag to edit the input file. On line 69 append `other.vcf` and also quit the input file processing.

N.B. the `other.vcf` is appended following line 69 and that the first command has to be separated from the first by a newline or a separate invocation of the `-e` flag.

```
sed -i $'69{r other_file\n;q}' file
```

Would also work if bash is the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

sed -n '1,69p' file.vcf > header.vcf && cat header.vcf otherfile > /tmp/abcd && mv /tmp/abcd otherfile